# Finding the repetition rate of output pulse

Tags: communication, digital-communications, telecommunications

I have finals coming up next week and I failed to solve this following problem, any help will be appreciated.

> An automatic translator, with a capacity of \$10^3 \frac{bits}{sec}\$
>   converts information from one coding system to another. Its input is a
>   train of uniformly spaced variable amplitude pulses, with \$2.71\times
>  10^5\$ pulses occurring each minute. Its output is another uniformly
>   spaced variable-amplitude pulse train, with one fifth the number of
>   possible amplitude levels as in the input. Find the repetition rate of
>   the output pulses.

How should I approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: Think of what is the amount of information contained in a single pulse for each case.

Comment: What should I calculate from input pulse train? I mean which element will help me to calculate the output pulse repetition?

Comment: A starting point might be to convert the rates to the same units - either bits/sec or bits per min.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the number of possible amplitudes for an input pulse is 
\$L_{in}=5 \cdot L_{out}\$. Then, you can transmit with two input pulses \$L_{in} \cdot L_{in}=L_{in}^2\$ different messages and with \$n\$ input pulses you can transmit \$L_{in}^n\$ different messages.

I will call the number of input pulses per second \$B_{in}\$ (\$B_{out}\$ for output pulses). If the translator is working without loss of information, the number of different messages you can encode in the input stream in one second should equal the number of different messages you can encode in the output stream in one second:

\$L_{in}^{B_{in}}=2^{10^3}=L_{out}^{B_{out}}\$

The term \$2^{10^3}\$ in this equation is the number of different messages one can encode in \$10^3\$ bits, the capacity of the translator for one second. In principle, we should be able to find the repetition rate of the output pulses, when we solve the above two equations for \$B_{out}\$.

However, your numbers make no sense to me because the number of input pulses per second would be

\$\frac{2.71 \cdot 10^5}{60} = 4516,6 \frac{pulses}{sec} > 1000 \frac{bits}{sec}\$.

This means, even when you had only two different amplitudes in the (then binary) input stream, the translator would be too slow to process the incoming data.